# Finding standard deviation using basic math functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get the standard deviation from a table containing income values, using the basic math functions below in postgresql.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT sqrt(sum(power(income - (sum(income) / count(income)), 2)) / (count(*) - 1)) FROM income_data
```

however, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

Has anyone run into this issue? I feel like the logic for obtaining the standard deviation should work, although haven't had any luck thus far, I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

Comment: Just use `stddev()`.  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: yes, I am aware stddev makes this easier, however, the idea is to use the basic math functions as the ones listed above and accomplish the same result as when using stddev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should calculate a mean in a separate query, e.g. in a with statement:

```
with mean as (
    select sum(income) / count(income) as mean
    from income_data
)
select sqrt(sum(power(income - mean, 2)) / (count(*) - 1)) 
from income_data
cross join mean;
```

or in a derived table:

```
select sqrt(sum(power(income - mean, 2)) / (count(*) - 1)) 
from income_data
cross join (
    select sum(income) / count(income) as mean
    from income_data
) s;
```